# Is it possible to process a Webpack loader completely before the others?

Tags: webpack

I am looking to build a loader that gathers all the resourcePaths, does some processing on them and later the subsequent loaders use that information. The problem I am facing is that all loaders are run on every module, I am unable to run a loader on all the module before running the rest of the loaders.

Comment: Not sure if I understand well your question, this may help: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-enforce if set to `'pre'` will run the loader before all other loaders, regardless its position (by default loaders run from top to bottom)